# How to implement image slide show using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried implementing it.But..the image changes from the first to the secnd and then stops.

for your reference,please find the code i tried to implemented.

```
<div id="images"> <img  name="slide" src="img/banner1.png"/>
<script type="text/javascript" >
var slideShow=document.getElementById("images");
var allImages= new Array();
allImages=["img/banner3.png","img/banner2.png","img/banner4.png","img/banner5.png"];
var imageIndex=0;
function changeImage()
{
    document.images.slide.src=allImages[imageIndex];
    //slideShow.setAtrribute("src",allImages[imageIndex]);
    console.log("executing 1");
    imageIndex++;
    if(imageIndex >= allImages.length)
    {
       console.log("executing 2");
       imageIndex=0;
    }
}console.log("executing 3");
setTimeout("changeImage()",1000);
console.log("executing 4");
</script>
</div>
```

Can Someone,help me in fixing this issue..Please!

Comment: Please make a JsFiddle File with some images..I will rectify your problem..!!

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/bretmorris/ULNa2/7/) for a reference.

Comment: @ Kishor Subedi,@Sree ram---[check this](http://jsfiddle.net/)  Pardon me..if any mistake..this was my first work on Jsfiddle

Comment: Yeah that's empty. Save it, then copy the link.

Comment: Your code works by changing `setTimeout` to `setInterval` function.
Check the answer below.

Comment: @user What user2361114 has posted is the exact code you are looking for..!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the infinite slide show use [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) instead of `setTimeout`.

```
setInterval('changeImage()',1000);
```

Your code works as fine after changing it. Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

This is the similar script you are searching for...

**Java Script**

```
slide=new Array("images/2.jpg","images/3.jpg","images/4.jpg","images/5.jpg","images/6.jpg","images/8.jpg")
pic=0;

function start()
{
setInterval("fun()",3000);
}

function fun()
{
document.show.src=slide[pic];
pic++;
if(pic==6)
pic=0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body onLoad="start();>
-------
-------
</body>
```